# node.js + mysql: "Cannot enqueue Handshake after already enqueuing a Handshake."

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, runtime-error

I'm attempting to make two functions, one which retrives an object from an SQL database, the other which saves an object to the same SQL database. I am using `node.js` and `mysql` to do this. I have two functions, `fetchEmployee` and `Employee.save`, which fetch and save an employee respectively. When I call `fetchEmployee`, and the callback includes `Employee.save`, however, I get the error `Cannot enqueue Handshake after already enqueuing a Handshake.` Even weirder, `Employee.save` seems to run before the error is thrown.

**EDIT**: `employee.save` appearing to run is a symptom of async, as `console.log("Saved!")` is called before the callback function passed to `SQL.parse` This means the error appears during the `parse`. Further, if within parse `console.log("connection created");` is added after `con.connect`, and `console.log("Made it out.");` is added after the end of `con.connect`, when calling `Employee.save`, the console outputs `> "connection created"`, then throws the error, meaning the save query is never finished, but the error is thrown after `con.connect`

The Employee class is defined by the following

```
function Employee(obj) {
    /** Defines the Employee class
     * @arg obj.id : an integer; the employee's id
     * @arg obj.name : A string; the employee's name
     * @arg obj.position : A string; the employee's positions split by commas
     */

    this.id = obj.id;
    this.name = obj.name;
    this.position = obj.position;

    this.save = function() {
        SQL.parse({
            sql : `UPDATE EMPLOYEES
                SET id=?, name=?, position=?
                WHERE id=?`,
                replace_ : [this.id, this.name, this.position, this.id],
                result : false
        });
        console.log("Saved!");
    }
}
```

Note the `console.log("Saved!");`, as this comes up later

`fetchEmployee` is defined by this function:

```
function fetchEmployee(id, callback) {
    /** Fetch an employee from the employee table
     * @arg id : An integer; the id of the employee to fetch
     * @arg callback : A callback function to pass the employee to
     */

     SQL.parse({ // Perform the parse, define the sql, replace, and result
        sql : "SELECT * FROM employees WHERE id=?",
        replace_ : [id],
        result : true
     },

     function(err, data) {
         if(err) { // Pass an error if there's an error
             callback(err, null);
             throw err;
         }
         // Pass the employee to the callback as an employee object if there's no errors
         callback(null, new Employee({  // data is passed as a list from the sql table, so take only the object we need through [0]
                id : data[0].id,
                name : data[0].name,
                position : data[0].position
             })
         );
     });
}
```

Finally, SQL.parse is defined in this file:

```
var mySQL = require("mysql");

var con = mySQL.createConnection({ //Create connection
    host : "localhost",
    database : "testdb1",
    user : "root",
    password : "***************" 
});

function parse(obj, callback) {
    /** Parses an sql query. 
     * @arg callback : A callback function, will be passed the data
     * @arg obj.sql : an sql query
     * @arg obj.replace_ : A list of replacements for ?s in sql
     * @arg obj.result : a boolean indicating whether a result should be returned
     */

     //Assign meaningfull values
     obj.replace_ = obj.replace_ || [];
     callback = callback || function() {};

    con.connect(function(err) {
        if(err) throw err;

        //Connect and pass the sql command to the server
        con.query(obj.sql, obj.replace_, function(err, data) {
            if(err) { //Pass the err to the callback if there is an err
                callback(err, null);
                throw err;
            }
            else if(obj.result) { // Pass the data to the callback if result is true
                callback(null, data)
            }
        });
    });
}

module.exports = {
    parse : parse
};
```

When I call this block of code

```
fetchEmployee(985, function(err, data) {
    if(err) throw err;
    console.log(data);
    data.save();
});
```

The console outputs

```
Employee {
  id: 985,
  name: 'Skidd',
  position: 'Dishwasher, Busser',
  save: [Function] }
Saved!
Error: Cannot enqueue Handshake after already enqueuing a Handshake. [...]
```

It appears to me that it correctly runs `fetchEmployee`, as data is logged to the console correctly with the data of the employee. It then logs `Saved!`, seeming to indicate that `Employee.save` ran correctly, then after all the code is done, throws the error. I can't for the life of me figure out why this would happen, here or on google or through testing.

I've tried to add `con.end` to the end of `parse` in `sql.js`, this changes the error to `Cannot enqueue Handshake after invoking quit`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem by placing

```
var con = mySQL.createConnection({ //Create connection
    host : "localhost",
    database : "testdb1",
    user : "root",
    password : "***************" 
});
```

inside of the `parse` function, though I'm not 100% sure why this worked.

Answer (score 0):

I followed what the previous person did and it worked for me too.
I guess the problem was the connection was being made asynchronously.
putting this inside the promise solved the problem

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).